# JQuery selector for specific element

Tags: jquery

I have a class called "name". On it i want to slideToggle its child div called 'beers'. I can figure out how to get all the 'beers' to toggle but I just want the specific div to open.

Heres my html

```
<div class="well well-sm">
  <h1 class="name">Barleys</h1>
  <hr>
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <% Beer.where(:store => "barleys", :popular => true).each do |beer| %>
       <p class = "beers"><%= link_to beer.name, "https://beeradvocate.com/search/?q=#   {beer.name.gsub(/\s/, '+')}" %></p></br>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.name').on('click', function(){
    $('.name .beers').slideToggle();
 })
})
```

This gives me nothing for toggle. And I dont want to use an id because I have multiple beer classes.

Comment: Which `div` do you want to open? The `container-fluid`?

Comment: Also, which *child div called 'beers'* are you talking about? There are only `p`s with the class `beers`.

Comment: That's not HTML, that's...something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this if you want to open all `beers` inside your clicked Element:

```
jQuery(this).parent().find('.beers')
```

Or this, if you want only the `container-fluid` to open:

```
jQuery(this).parent().find('.container-fluid')
```

---

That works, because

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/